# Unknown error media file when playing local mp3

Tags: java, android

I have a problem when i want to play an mp3 file in the memory card shows "Unknown error media file"  on galaxy note3 , galaxy s3 and galaxy s5 how can solve the problem ?? the file playing normaly with android music player but in my program not working .thanks

```
 MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
 mp.setDataSource(PATH_TO_FILE);
 mp.prepare();
 mp.start();
```

sorry for bad english

Comment: Can you please post log cat ?

Comment: When media player catch the error shows"MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN  (1, -2147483648) " but mp3 file working using android music player

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, error -2147483648 indicates an unknown error. This could have something to do with the mp3 encoding, but it's also worth checking that the file path exists and that the MediaPlayer has permission to read it.

My issue was that I was writing my files with Context.MODE_PRIVATE (the default).

```
openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

This indicates that only your application can access the file. I don't know specifically how or why, but in Jelly Bean and above, it appears that the video view is allowed to access the file you specify as if it were your application, but before Jelly Bean, the video view tries to open the file in its own context (not your application's). Since the mode is private, it fails.

One solution is to write your file with [Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_WORLD_READABLE), which is now deprecated. This indicates that anyone can open the file at that path. This is obviously unsafe and discouraged.

This fixes my issue and hopefully yours, too!

Try this :

```
MediaPlayer mpintro =     MediaPlayer.create(this,Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+ "/Music/intro.mp3"));// example for path
        mpintro.setLooping(true);
        mpintro.start();
```

Comment: thanks for your comment ...i am downloading the mp3 file using andriod download manager and i dont hava problem with this every thing work fine but in some device not playing ... i dont know what i do to slove it :'(
this my app on play store https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.RozhanTeam.MuhammadMalaFayaq

Comment: This is due to encoding issue. please refer this http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Comment: how can solve it KishuDroid? mp3 supported by android device but in my program cant play

Comment: Try to play it using
  Intent intent = new Intent();  
        intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);  
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(path), "audio/*");  
        startActivity(intent);

Comment: I dont want to use intent ...any help

Comment: just try play , does it working with native android player?

Comment: yes its work with native player but in my app not work and also work fine when streaming in web